# How can a matrix multiplication equation be solved for single variable

Tags: linear-algebra

How do you, find all values of *k*, if any, that satisfy the equation

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
k & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 2 & -3
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
k \\
1 \\
 1
\end{bmatrix} = 0
$$

The text indicates the answer is -1, but I don't see how to arrive at this answer.

Comment: Just multiply it out. It will give the equation $(k+1)^2 = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easy enough to do directly:  If you matrix is $A$ and $v^T = (k,1,1)$ then
$$ A v = \left( \begin{array}{c} k+1\\k+2\\-1\end{array} \right) $$ and
$$ v^T A v = (k, 1, 1) \left( \begin{array}{c} k+1\\k+2\\-1\end{array} \right) = k^2 + 2k + 1$$

and then $ k^2 + 2k + 1 = 0$ has only one root, at $k=-1$.